# bucket time duration dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to bucket a datetime duration dataframe with pandas.
example:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ts':   [1, 5, 10, 12],
    'dur':  [1, 2,  6, 6],
})
print(df)

     ts  dur
 0   1    1
 1   5    2
 2  10    6
 3  12    6
```

I need to bucket it with 3, so:

[image]

```
bin1, 1
bin2, 2
bin3, 0
bin4, 4
bin5, 6
bin6, 2
```

What's proper way to do it with pandas?

*Update
To follow up @Pieree D's answer, it's great for above example. One problem if I use `ns` as unit and data more bigger as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
import io

def bucket(df,ts,dur,span):
    freq = 'ns'  # could be 's' if preferred
    dfs = pd.to_timedelta(df[ts], unit=freq)  # start, inclusive
    dfe = df[ts] + df[dur]
    dfe = pd.to_timedelta(dfe, unit=freq)  # end, exclusive
    dfout = pd.concat([
        pd.Series(1, index=dfs),  # start: +1
        pd.Series(-1, index=dfe),  # end: -1
    ]).resample(freq).sum().cumsum().resample(
        f'{span}{freq}', origin='start',
    ).sum().reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis('bin')
    dfout = dfout.to_frame()
    dfout.columns= ['sum']
    dfout[ts] = df[ts].min() + dfout.index*span
    return dfout

csvdata = '''ts,dur
19318744574,391823
21320087699,527291
23322650667,345208
25325015510,355729
27327401707,356354
29329792123,464531
31332296861,408802
32596494257,1131354
32738075298,416459'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csvdata))
df = bucket(df,'ts','dur',50)
print(df)
```

Then python report error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 100. GiB for an array with shape (13419747184,) and data type int64
```

Maybe need to consider to use sparse solution?

Comment: Can you explain "*bin 2 is from 4 to 6, dursum is 0 + 1 = 1*"? Where are the 0/1 coming from?

Comment: Update a diagram to show what does bucket 3 mean. and fix bin values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update for large cases

My original answer (below) takes `O(max(ts + dur) - min(ts))` in space (before the final resampling). When that is too large, the following sparse version should be used instead. Note that it will skip bins containing `0` in the answer. (Note that, if speed is also an issue, we can still do better in pure Numpy).

```py
def bin_k(t, dur, binsize=3):
    i, j = t // binsize, 1 + (t + dur - 1) // binsize
    a = np.arange(i, j)
    return a

def bin_w(t, dur, binsize=3):
    n = 1 + (t + dur - 1) // binsize - t // binsize
    a = np.repeat(binsize, n)
    adj0 = t % binsize
    adj1 = n * binsize - adj0 - dur
    a[0] -= adj0
    a[-1] -= adj1
    return a

def bucket(df, ts='ts', dur='dur', span=3):
    z = df.assign(ts=df[ts] - df[ts].min())
    out = z.assign(
        bin=z[[ts, dur]].apply(lambda r: bin_k(*r, binsize=span), axis=1),
        val=z[[ts, dur]].apply(lambda r: bin_w(*r, binsize=span), axis=1),
    ).explode(['bin', 'val']).groupby('bin')['val'].sum()
    return out
```

Example on the OP's large data:

```py
>>> bucket(df, span=50)
bin
0            50
1            50
2            50
3            50
4            50
             ..
268394939    50
268394940    50
268394941    50
268394942    50
268394943    33
Name: val, Length: 87961, dtype: object
```

#### How does it work?

Let's use the small OP's example:

```py
z = df.assign(ts=df['ts'] - df['ts'].min())
>>> z.assign(
...     bin=z[['ts', 'dur']].apply(lambda r: bin_k(*r), axis=1),
...     val=z[['ts', 'dur']].apply(lambda r: bin_w(*r), axis=1),
... )
   ts  dur        bin        val
0   0    1        [0]        [1]
1   4    2        [1]        [2]
2   9    6     [3, 4]     [3, 3]
3  11    6  [3, 4, 5]  [1, 3, 2]
```

In other words, we make bins and values, each a Numpy array, for each  row, by simple arithmetic.

After that, we `.explode()` those columns, group by bin and sum.

## Original answer

The plot was key for me to understand what you are looking for. You want to define interval covers, then group those in bins.

First, the code, and further below an explanation.

```py
freq = 'D'  # could be 's' if preferred
ts = pd.to_timedelta(df['ts'], unit=freq)  # start, inclusive
te = pd.to_timedelta(df['ts'] + df['dur'], unit=freq)  # end, exclusive
z = pd.concat([
    pd.Series(1, index=ts),  # start: +1
    pd.Series(-1, index=te),  # end: -1
]).resample(freq).sum().cumsum().resample(
    f'3{freq}', origin='start',
).sum().reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis('bin')

>>> z
bin
0    1
1    2
2    0
3    4
4    6
5    2
```

#### Explanation

We encode each `ts, dur` pair as `ts, te`: start (inclusive) and end (exclusive). At the start, we add 1, and the end, we subtract 1. At that point, we can resample by 1 (freq):

```py
z = pd.concat([
    pd.Series(1, index=ts),  # start: +1
    pd.Series(-1, index=te),  # end: -1
]).resample(freq).sum()

>>> z.to_frame('change').assign(cover=z.cumsum())
         change  cover
1 days        1      1
2 days       -1      0
3 days        0      0
4 days        0      0
5 days        1      1
6 days        0      1
7 days       -1      0
8 days        0      0
9 days        0      0
10 days       1      1
11 days       0      1
12 days       1      2
13 days       0      2
14 days       0      2
15 days       0      2
16 days      -1      1
17 days       0      1
18 days      -1      0
```

The `+1` and `-1` at starts and ends, respectively, indicate change in cover. The `.cumsum()` of those is the cover. As you can see, that corresponds to how many blue lines are above the point at that axis. Finally, we resample to the bins we want.

Comment: Awesome, that what I want. it's amazing to implement it in few lines. what's the reason use pd.Series instead of dataframe? series performance  better?

Comment: The quantity `z` is a 1-dimensional array, so a `Series` is perfectly appropriate for this. You can make a `DataFrame` with only one column, and it would be fine too, but perhaps less clear. Note that, if the bins (and the durations) are much bigger, more optimized and sparse solutions exist.

Comment: Exactly, I found if I use 'ns' as unit, it will fail, would you please help sparse solution as well?

Comment: Thanks, I add a update section with a example, data number not big but the number it's self is int64. error message pasted.

Comment: updated with a sparse version.